# embed picture into Jupiter notebook, can't get the correct path of local picture/file

Tags: python, html, jupyter-notebook, markdown, jupyter

I tried the below:

```
![pic](/Users/kloe/Desktop/screenshot20201005.png)
```

and

```
<img src='/Users/kloe/Desktop/screenshot20201005.png'>
```

None of the above works. However, the below code works perfectly and showing the picture from a website:

```
<img src='https://pic4.zhimg.com/80/v2-a1bbd4726f082fdee940ba102b0707d4_1440w.jpg?source=1940ef5c' width='400'>
```

So I'm thinking probably the path of the local picture was wrong?
I saw there's an error message on terminal when I try to insert the local pic:

```
404 GET /Users/kloe/Desktop/screenshot20201005.png
```

I'm using macOS Catalina 10.15.7. I download Jupiter notebook by using pip, and opened the Jupiter notebook via terminal and currently running on safari.

I got the path of the picture by drag the picture to terminal. Does anyone know what's going on? or how do I get the correct path that can be recognized by Jupiter Notebook?Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** Try dragging and dropping the image into a markdown cell as well!

You may try navigating through the directories using

```
cd
```

which lists the current directory

and

```
ls
```

which lists the subdirectories.

Use Tab for auto-completes and navigate to your image, copy that directory and if it is a directory issue that should solve it!

Comment: thank you for your answer! someone has the similar issue said it was caused by One Drive that changed the files path on pc, which sounds pretty complex. I decided to uploaded the picture online, and it works now, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

if your on mac you can

1. click on the photo once(dont open)
2. press file > get info
3. look for where and that is your path

Comment: Thank you for the reply, “/Users/kloe/Desktop”------it's the same as shown in terminal, which Jupiter notebook can't recognized, I don't why...